# Why can the project can use resource without import R file?

Tags: android

I read the sourec code RangeSeekBar.java in https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar/tree/master/rangeseekbar

Normally, in order to use string resource file, we should "import info.dao.myapp.R;"

But in the RangeSeekBar.java, I can't find any resource file import , but the class can use *`R.string.demo_min_label`*, why?

```
package org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.florescu.android.util.BitmapUtil;
import org.florescu.android.util.PixelUtil;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

 */
public class RangeSeekBar<T extends Number> extends ImageView {
    /**
     * Default color of a {@link RangeSeekBar}, #FF33B5E5. This is also known as "Ice Cream Sandwich" blue.
     */
    public static final int ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.argb(0xFF, 0x33, 0xB5, 0xE5);
    /**
     * An invalid pointer id.
     */
    public static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 255;

    // Localized constants from MotionEvent for compatibility
    // with API < 8 "Froyo".
    public static final int ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK = 0x0000ff00, ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT = 8;

    public static final Integer DEFAULT_MINIMUM = 0;
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_MAXIMUM = 100;
    public static final int HEIGHT_IN_DP = 30;
    public static final int TEXT_LATERAL_PADDING_IN_DP = 3;

    private static final int INITIAL_PADDING_IN_DP = 8;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE_IN_DP = 14;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_DISTANCE_TO_BUTTON_IN_DP = 8;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_DISTANCE_TO_TOP_IN_DP = 8;

    private static final int LINE_HEIGHT_IN_DP = 1;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint shadowPaint = new Paint();

    private Bitmap thumbImage;
    private Bitmap thumbPressedImage;
    private Bitmap thumbDisabledImage;

    private float mThumbHalfWidth;
    private float mThumbHalfHeight;

    private float padding;
    private T absoluteMinValue, absoluteMaxValue;
    private NumberType numberType;
    private double absoluteMinValuePrim, absoluteMaxValuePrim;
    private double normalizedMinValue = 0d;
    private double normalizedMaxValue = 1d;
    private Thumb pressedThumb = null;
    private boolean notifyWhileDragging = false;
    private OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener;

    private float mDownMotionX;

    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private int mScaledTouchSlop;

    private boolean mIsDragging;

    private int mTextOffset;
    private int mTextSize;
    private int mDistanceToTop;
    private RectF mRect;

    private boolean mSingleThumb;
    private boolean mAlwaysActive;
    private boolean mShowLabels;
    private boolean mShowTextAboveThumbs;
    private float mInternalPad;
    private int mActiveColor;
    private int mDefaultColor;
    private int mTextAboveThumbsColor;

    private boolean mThumbShadow;
    private int mThumbShadowXOffset;
    private int mThumbShadowYOffset;
    private int mThumbShadowBlur;
    private Path mThumbShadowPath;
    private Path mTranslatedThumbShadowPath = new Path();
    private Matrix mThumbShadowMatrix = new Matrix();

    private boolean mActivateOnDefaultValues;


    public RangeSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public RangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public RangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T extractNumericValueFromAttributes(TypedArray a, int attribute, int defaultValue) {
        TypedValue tv = a.peekValue(attribute);
        if (tv == null) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(defaultValue);
        }

        int type = tv.type;
        if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_FLOAT) {
            return (T) Float.valueOf(a.getFloat(attribute, defaultValue));
        } else {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(a.getInteger(attribute, defaultValue));
        }
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        float barHeight;
        int thumbNormal = R.drawable.seek_thumb_normal;
        int thumbPressed = R.drawable.seek_thumb_pressed;
        int thumbDisabled = R.drawable.seek_thumb_disabled;
        int thumbShadowColor;
        int defaultShadowColor = Color.argb(75, 0, 0, 0);
        int defaultShadowYOffset = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, 2);
        int defaultShadowXOffset = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, 0);
        int defaultShadowBlur = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, 2);

        if (attrs == null) {
            setRangeToDefaultValues();
            mInternalPad = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, INITIAL_PADDING_IN_DP);
            barHeight = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, LINE_HEIGHT_IN_DP);
            mActiveColor = ACTIVE_COLOR;
            mDefaultColor = Color.GRAY;
            mAlwaysActive = false;
            mShowTextAboveThumbs = true;
            mTextAboveThumbsColor = Color.WHITE;
            thumbShadowColor = defaultShadowColor;
            mThumbShadowXOffset = defaultShadowXOffset;
            mThumbShadowYOffset = defaultShadowYOffset;
            mThumbShadowBlur = defaultShadowBlur;
            mActivateOnDefaultValues = false;
        } else {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RangeSeekBar, 0, 0);
            try {
                setRangeValues(
                        extractNumericValueFromAttributes(a, R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_absoluteMinValue, DEFAULT_MINIMUM),
                        extractNumericValueFromAttributes(a, R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_absoluteMaxValue, DEFAULT_MAXIMUM)
                );
                mShowTextAboveThumbs = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_valuesAboveThumbs, true);
                mTextAboveThumbsColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_textAboveThumbsColor, Color.WHITE);
                mSingleThumb = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_singleThumb, false);
                mShowLabels = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_showLabels, true);
                mInternalPad = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_internalPadding, INITIAL_PADDING_IN_DP);
                barHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_barHeight, LINE_HEIGHT_IN_DP);
                mActiveColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_activeColor, ACTIVE_COLOR);
                mDefaultColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_defaultColor, Color.GRAY);
                mAlwaysActive = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_alwaysActive, false);

                Drawable normalDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbNormal);
                if (normalDrawable != null) {
                    thumbImage = BitmapUtil.drawableToBitmap(normalDrawable);
                }
                Drawable disabledDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbDisabled);
                if (disabledDrawable != null) {
                    thumbDisabledImage = BitmapUtil.drawableToBitmap(disabledDrawable);
                }
                Drawable pressedDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbPressed);
                if (pressedDrawable != null) {
                    thumbPressedImage = BitmapUtil.drawableToBitmap(pressedDrawable);
                }
                mThumbShadow = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbShadow, false);
                thumbShadowColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbShadowColor, defaultShadowColor);
                mThumbShadowXOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbShadowXOffset, defaultShadowXOffset);
                mThumbShadowYOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbShadowYOffset, defaultShadowYOffset);
                mThumbShadowBlur = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_thumbShadowBlur, defaultShadowBlur);

                mActivateOnDefaultValues = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_activateOnDefaultValues, false);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

        if (thumbImage == null) {
            thumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), thumbNormal);
        }
        if (thumbPressedImage == null) {
            thumbPressedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), thumbPressed);
        }
        if (thumbDisabledImage == null) {
            thumbDisabledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), thumbDisabled);
        }

        mThumbHalfWidth = 0.5f * thumbImage.getWidth();
        mThumbHalfHeight = 0.5f * thumbImage.getHeight();

        setValuePrimAndNumberType();

        mTextSize = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE_IN_DP);
        mDistanceToTop = PixelUtil.dpToPx(context, DEFAULT_TEXT_DISTANCE_TO_TOP_IN_DP);
        mTextOffset = !mShowTextAboveThumbs ? 0 : this.mTextSize + PixelUtil.dpToPx(context,
                DEFAULT_TEXT_DISTANCE_TO_BUTTON_IN_DP) + this.mDistanceToTop;

        mRect = new RectF(padding,
                mTextOffset + mThumbHalfHeight - barHeight / 2,
                getWidth() - padding,
                mTextOffset + mThumbHalfHeight + barHeight / 2);

        // make RangeSeekBar focusable. This solves focus handling issues in case EditText widgets are being used along with the RangeSeekBar within ScrollViews.
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mScaledTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();

        if (mThumbShadow) {
            // We need to remove hardware acceleration in order to blur the shadow
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            shadowPaint.setColor(thumbShadowColor);
            shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(mThumbShadowBlur, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
            mThumbShadowPath = new Path();
            mThumbShadowPath.addCircle(0,
                    0,
                    mThumbHalfHeight,
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // only used to set default values when initialised from XML without any values specified
    private void setRangeToDefaultValues() {
        this.absoluteMinValue = (T) DEFAULT_MINIMUM;
        this.absoluteMaxValue = (T) DEFAULT_MAXIMUM;
        setValuePrimAndNumberType();
    }

    private void setValuePrimAndNumberType() {
        absoluteMinValuePrim = absoluteMinValue.doubleValue();
        absoluteMaxValuePrim = absoluteMaxValue.doubleValue();
        numberType = NumberType.fromNumber(absoluteMinValue);
    }

    /**
     * Should the widget notify the listener callback while the user is still dragging a thumb? Default is false.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setNotifyWhileDragging(boolean flag) {
        this.notifyWhileDragging = flag;
    }



    /**
     * Returns the currently selected min value.
     *
     * @return The currently selected min value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMinValue() {
        return normalizedToValue(normalizedMinValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected minimum value. The widget will be invalidated and redrawn.
     *
     * @param value The Number value to set the minimum value to. Will be clamped to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMinValue(T value) {
        // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero when normalizing.
        if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
            setNormalizedMinValue(0d);
        } else {
            setNormalizedMinValue(valueToNormalized(value));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently selected max value.
     *
     * @return The currently selected max value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMaxValue() {
        return normalizedToValue(normalizedMaxValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected maximum value. The widget will be invalidated and redrawn.
     *
     * @param value The Number value to set the maximum value to. Will be clamped to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMaxValue(T value) {
        // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero when normalizing.
        if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
            setNormalizedMaxValue(1d);
        } else {
            setNormalizedMaxValue(valueToNormalized(value));
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setThumbShadowPath(Path thumbShadowPath) {
        this.mThumbShadowPath = thumbShadowPath;
    }




    /**
     * Draws the widget on the given canvas.
     */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(mDefaultColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        float minMaxLabelSize = 0;

        if (mShowLabels) {
            // draw min and max labels
            String minLabel = getContext().getString(R.string.demo_min_label);
            String maxLabel = getContext().getString(R.string.demo_max_label);
            minMaxLabelSize = Math.max(paint.measureText(minLabel), paint.measureText(maxLabel));
            float minMaxHeight = mTextOffset + mThumbHalfHeight + mTextSize / 3;
            canvas.drawText(minLabel, 0, minMaxHeight, paint);
            canvas.drawText(maxLabel, getWidth() - minMaxLabelSize, minMaxHeight, paint);
        }
        padding = mInternalPad + minMaxLabelSize + mThumbHalfWidth;

        // draw seek bar background line
        mRect.left = padding;
        mRect.right = getWidth() - padding;
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, paint);

        boolean selectedValuesAreDefault = (getSelectedMinValue().equals(getAbsoluteMinValue()) &&
                getSelectedMaxValue().equals(getAbsoluteMaxValue()));

        int colorToUseForButtonsAndHighlightedLine = !mAlwaysActive && !mActivateOnDefaultValues && selectedValuesAreDefault ?
                mDefaultColor : // default values
                mActiveColor;   // non default, filter is active

        // draw seek bar active range line
        mRect.left = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue);
        mRect.right = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue);

        paint.setColor(colorToUseForButtonsAndHighlightedLine);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, paint);

        // draw minimum thumb (& shadow if requested) if not a single thumb control
        if (!mSingleThumb) {
            if (mThumbShadow) {
                drawThumbShadow(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue), canvas);
            }
            drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue), Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb), canvas,
                    selectedValuesAreDefault);
        }

        // draw maximum thumb & shadow (if necessary)
        if (mThumbShadow) {
            drawThumbShadow(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue), canvas);
        }
        drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue), Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb), canvas,
                selectedValuesAreDefault);

        // draw the text if sliders have moved from default edges
        if (mShowTextAboveThumbs && (mActivateOnDefaultValues || !selectedValuesAreDefault)) {
            paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            paint.setColor(mTextAboveThumbsColor);
            // give text a bit more space here so it doesn't get cut off
            int offset = PixelUtil.dpToPx(getContext(), TEXT_LATERAL_PADDING_IN_DP);

            String minText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMinValue());
            String maxText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMaxValue());
            float minTextWidth = paint.measureText(minText) + offset;
            float maxTextWidth = paint.measureText(maxText) + offset;

            if (!mSingleThumb) {
                canvas.drawText(minText,
                        normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue) - minTextWidth * 0.5f,
                        mDistanceToTop + mTextSize,
                        paint);

            }

            canvas.drawText(maxText,
                    normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue) - maxTextWidth * 0.5f,
                    mDistanceToTop + mTextSize,
                    paint);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

But have you tried the git the project to your workspace and build it locally successful?

Comment: Yes! it locally successful

Comment: So I'm very strange that how RangeSeekBar.java invoke  the R resource file without import